# Avoid auto indent when saving in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, save, indentation

I want to **avoid auto indent behaviour when I save** a (javascript) file in Visual Studio Code without turning off complety auto indentation.

I have this code (and I would like to keep this indentation if possible):

```
const $tab_a = $('tab_a')
const $tab_b = $('tab_b')

;[$tab_a, $tab_b].forEach($e => $e.onclick = () => {
  if ($e.className) return
  $tab_a.classList.toggle('active')
  $tab_b.classList.toggle('active')
})
```

However, every time I save with Visual Studio Code it changes indentation like this:

```
const $tab_a = $('tab_a')
const $tab_b = $('tab_b')

  ;[$tab_a, $tab_b].forEach($e => $e.onclick = () => {
    if ($e.className) return
    $tab_a.classList.toggle('active')
    $tab_b.classList.toggle('active')
  })
```

I tried different settings in Visual Studio Code:

1. Editor: Auto Indent (default: full) -> none
2. Editor: Wrapping Indent (default: same) -> none
3. All combinations and restarting VSCode

Unfortunatly any of them worked for me.

Any help will be really appreciate it.

**Note**: I'm not using extensions.

Comment: Or just put the `;` where they belong in the first place. ;-)

Comment: Seems like a bug in the default formatter, though, which may be worth reporting (and perhaps even trying to fix and doing PR). You shouldn't have to turn off format-on-save just to avoid it formatting your code incorrectly. (Even if I too prefer to just put the semis where the grammar expects them rather than only where ASI won't work correctly, not least for reasons like this...)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To turn off formatting on save:

1. Go to **File | Preferences > Settings**
2. Type "save" in the search box
3. In the list, choose **Text Editor | Formatting**
4. Untick the box for **Editor: Format On Save**

That sets the `"editor.formatOnSave"` setting to `false` in `settings.json`.

When I did that, your example was left alone when I saved the file. (Whereas with the setting on, it gets reformatted as you describe in the question when I save it.)

Comment: This is not suitable since it will disable every formatting on save. The best would have been to only disable indentation (as the title of post suggests). BTW I can't believe you have 1 million rep, never saw this before!!

Comment: @TOPKAT - Yeah, it's an all-or-nothing thing unless you write your own formatter. (Re rep: I'm not even the top-ranked user, though I am #6. :-) #1 is Jon Skeet, currently at about 1.4M - https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all )

Answer (score 3):

check setting.json (ctrl+shift+p then choose 'Preferences: Open Settings (Json)' ) for:

`"editor.formatOnSave": true/flase`

it should be set by default to false but maybe some extension toggled to true so just change it back to false.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, when I hit save for my **js** file it was indented with **4 spaces instead of 2**.

I found this github thread  [File reformatting to 4 spaces for indentation on save. #28327](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/28327)

Then I searched for **JS-CSS-HTML Formatter extension**, which was installed, so I proceeded to configure it:

```
Press F1, enter Formatter Config, open the config file:
```

It will open the settings in a new tab and you just need to adjust the option **indent_size** from 4 to 2